# Selenium -- Click on a blank area of an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<td width="14%" height="90" valign="top" id="cell_saturday1" name="06/02/2018" onclick="onClick(this);">
<table width="100%" height="30" id="table_saturday1"></table>
</td>
```

Is there any way I can click anywhere on **td** in above code not containing **table** with the id table_saturday1?

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: is td clickable manually ?

Comment: yes td is clickable. But I want to avoid clicking on the table which is in td

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Xpath to click on td which is clickable :

```
//td[@id='cell_saturday1' and @name='06/02/2018' and contains(@onclick,'onClick(this);')]
```

Comment: This should work , try to use explicit wait if it throws any exception related to excepted conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with javascript executor as given below.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('cell_saturday1').click();");
```

or

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("cell_saturday1"));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",ele);
```

or Using action class

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.moveToElement(ele, 0, 0).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: I had a similar issue where the FirefoxDriver (Chrome and IE were fine) was not appearing to click on the cell.  Using the Actions approach and specifying an X offset of 5 fixed the issue. I guess it was clicking on the border or off to the side of the cell for some reason.

`Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.moveToElement(ele, 0, 5).click().build().perform();`

Answer (score 0):

To click anywhere within the `<td>` except the childnode `<table>` with `id` as **table_saturday1** you can use the following Locator Strategy
[Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) :

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  "td#cell_saturday1:not(#table_saturday1)"
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  "//td[@id='cell_saturday1' and not(@id='table_saturday1')]"
  ```